# Kentico CSS issue

Tags: css, kentico

I am using Kentico and have noticed a weird css issue. After mocking my pages up in Dreamweaver I then create the page in Kentico, however I have noticed that some elements in Kentico are slightly misaligned.

I have tried copying the source from Kentico into Dreamweaver to see if I can fix the issue but Kentico still renders the content incorrectly.

Comment: Mark are you using aspx pages when you're creating them in Dreamweaver?  If not, this may cause some issues due to the way an asp.net website works and renders markup.

Comment: An old post I know, but I wanted to ask if the pages looked misaligned in the Pages application or on the live site itself?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Dreamweaver in design or split mode? if yes, turn it off and use code mode only.

Comment: Hi, 

No code only but I don't think that's the issue anyway as I am working directly on my dev server and IIS is serving the pages.

Comment: This will not provide any kind of fix for the OP's issue.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have to compare structure of your HTML and Kentico output HTML. Kentico add a form tag by default which may cause structural issue with css. If you can provide both html, I can help

Answer (score 0):

On Kentico (up to version 11) when you use portal engine or ASPX templates you have this shortcoming. Kentico adds excessive HTML markup on the controls it creates on order to provide hooks that will help the engine to perform actions. For example, Bizforms add multiple divs/spans around normal input tags. So, you have to adapt the CSS you have created to match the tags used by Kentico.

Answer (score 0):

What is your template type:
ASPX page: You can copy your entire HTML code from Dreamweaver into your aspx page template and then work on your page.

Portal Page: You need to understand the structure and cannot replace entire HTML Code from Dreamweaver. You have to seperate your HTML code to insert DropZone for web parts and widgets.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

You will have to make some adaptation always from raw HTML and kentico. In your case you are using aspx model which makes it more harder as server level changes are not 100% compatible with raw HTML or client side code. If possible use portal engine with transformation which will be more like to like of raw HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You must create a directory in CSS/Stylesheet

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the CSS section of the Admin interface, check to see if you have any  & signs at the beginning of any tags. Kentico doesn't seem to support this so might be breaking any classes that appear after it.